# Using Qt, how do I detect if a Windows registry key exists

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to use Qt to detect if .Net is installed on the client machine.

```
 QSettings netKey(
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4",
    QSettings::NativeFormat);

    if(!netKey){ //what do I check here to see if the key was found??

    }
```

Edit:

This works but is detecting a value, not a key.

```
// path is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\client"

if(netKey.value("InstallPath").isNull()){
// this works but is detecting a value, not key
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [QSettings documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsettings.html), in the section "Accessing the Windows Registry Directly". Use the value() method to obtain the value of a key, or contains() to check if a key exists.

Comment: I tried both .value and .contains with "default" and ".", checking isNull or isValid but they always return false :/

Comment: it seems that since default is blank for the key, it is not detected. I was able to detect a sub key with an actual value. But still not sure how to detect if an actual key (not value) exists.

Comment: netKey.contains("InstallPath")?